# MS SQL server Index/PK recommendations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause

I am having a few issues with a very slow UPDATE statement using two tables with a large number of rows.

I'm unfamiliar with the use of primary keys and indexes, which is no doubt a part of the problem, but I'm also concerned it may have something to do with the fact that I am using a 32bit version of MS SQL server.

The data is imported from two old Visual Fox Pro *.DBF files. 
As the data has typos and other errors, I first imported them into two temp tables, as varchar(255) data types. 
I then cleaned/edited these temp tables to ensure the columns I'm interested in were in the correct datatype.
Then I imported them into two tables, named WORK and MAST.
That all worked fine, albeit slowly.

Both tables contain mainly varchar(50), but also int, tinyint, decimal and date data types.

WORK contains approx 600,000 rows, with 21 fields.

MAST contains approx 6,500,000 rows, with 26 fields.

The main slowless arose when I tried to copy three rows from MAST into three rows in WORK, using the following query. 
It took 4 hours to complete.

```
USE DATABASE
UPDATE WORK
SET w_timeOS = t2.m_timeOS,
w_distance = t2.m_distance,
w_state = t2.m_state
FROM MAST as t2
WHERE
WORK.w_date = t2.m_date
and WORK.w_siteNum = t2.m_SiteNum
and WORK.w_location = t2.m_location
```

In the set statement, the timeOS and distance fields are integers and the states are varchar(5).

In the where clause, the date values are date formatted, the siteNum are integer and the locations are varchar(1), which I guess I should convert the location to integer...

Where, on what would you recommend putting an index?

The date, siteNum and location, combined, are unique to MAST, and they are also all in WORK, however there may be several matching rows for each combination of those fields in the WORK table.

However, if I add another field, w_employee, then they would be unique in the WORK table as well.

Should I add an index using w_date,w_siteNum and w_location on the WORK table?

Should I also add an index to m_date, m_siteNum and m_location in the MAST table, which, as mentioned above, would not be unique, unless I added m_employee?

Or is there some better way, (perhaps using them as foreign keys?), given both tables essentially share the same information of all three fields, even though they are only unique on MAST, requiring adding the m_employee field on the WORK table to make it unique?

Would a join be better than the three where clauses?

Does the time it takes seem excessive to you, even given the current lack of indexes?

I'm running MS SQL Server 12.0.2000, 32 Bit, and using MSMS 17.6, on a Windows 7 64bit system with an AMD Dual Core FX-4100 CPU at 3.6GHz, 8GB DDR3 RAM, with a virtually empty 1TB 7200RPM 6GB/s SATA hard disk, on which the OS, SQL and MSMS are installed.

Watching the system resources, no CPU core gets to 50%, the RAM used by the system is less than 4GB, SQL server itself uses around 1.5GB.

The hard disk access seems very slow at around 2MB/s. Ive tested the hard disk, and found no bad or pending bad sectors.

From that, I suspect it isn't an issue with the system specs, or the fact that its running a 32bit version of SQL, as from what I've read it supports up to 2.5GB of RAM on the 32bit version.

Any suggestions, pointers, etc, would be greatly appreciated. 
I've spend an hour or so trying to draft this, in the hope it is concise, so I'm sorry if its not.
I apologise if its too verbose, but I've tried to add as much information I think is relevant.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: The general rule says to create an index on the column which is in where clause and use for filtration. Although, It might be dangerous sometime in your case you can achieve this. On the other note if the table has a large number of records then try to update the data in chunks using some condition , while loop or fast forward cursor.

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestions Rajat, I appreciate it. 
I have created an index, as you, and as Gordon, have suggested. I was hoping to avoid having to do the updates in chunks, so fortunately adding the index helped to improve the speed - from 4 hours to around 30 minutes. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
UPDATE WORK
SET w_timeOS = t2.m_timeOS,
    w_distance = t2.m_distance,
    w_state = t2.m_state
FROM MAST as t2
WHERE WORK.w_date = t2.m_date and
      WORK.w_siteNum = t2.m_SiteNum and
      WORK.w_location = t2.m_location  ;
```

You want an index on `MAST(m_date, m_siteNum, m_location)`.  And index on the three fields might also help in `WORK`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I had played around with putting an index on WORK, which didn't seem to really help... although not 100% sure on that...
I did however put an index on the fields you suggested, ON the MAST table, and the time dropped from just over 4 hours to around 30 minutes. I am very happy with that, an eight fold improvement. 
Thanks so much for your help.